# R ggplot: geomsmooth 95% CI instead of standard error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following plot:

[image]

But the `geom_smooth` now displays the standard errors, but I would like to `95%` `CI` around the lines. Is there an easy fix for this?

I used the following code:

```
MMSEmodel <- (lmer(MMSE~ Age + Eduy + Gender + study +     DateMMSE*AMYLOID_BL*BL_Diaggroups + (1 + DateMMSE|study), seleduy)

fitMMSE <- fitted(MMSEmodel)


MMSEplot <- qplot(DateMMSE, fitMMSE, data=seleduy, geom=c("smooth"), method="glm", color=BL_Diaggroups, linetype=AMYLOID_BL, fill=BL_Diaggroups)+ theme_classic() + xlab("Time (years)") + ylab("MMSE") + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,4), ylim = c(15,30)) + scale_color_manual(values=c("#339900", "#FF6600", "#0000CC")) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#66CC66", "#FF9966", "#3366FF")) + scale_linetype(guide_legend(title = "Amyloid status")) + guides(lty = guide_legend(override.aes = list(col = 'black')))
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show your code, not just the output. How to fix it depends on how you have coded it.

Comment: Sorry! I added the code now.

Answer (score 1):

From `ggplot2` documentation for `stat_smooth` :

> se
>   display confidence interval around smooth? (TRUE by default, see level to control

Since in your code I don't see any arguments to overwrite the default settings- the se bands show the 95% confidence interval. To change these to say 90% or 99% etc look up `level`